# where to place .htaccess on elastic beanstalk python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to remove the www from the url, and normally I do this by using a .htaccess file with a rewrite rule. I don't know where to put this file in my elastic beanstalk folder structure, or where to have it created.

I've tried placing my .htaccess in 
1. /var/www/html
2. django application folder
3. the same folder as the wsgi
4. the django templates folder
5. in the root of my project folder.

None of these have made any difference. I would be interested either where to place the .htaccess file, or another way to remove the www that might be django specific.

Comment: Facing a similar problem. Have you found a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's AllowOverride is set to None by default. You have to do some *.ebextensions* touches to change the default AllowOverride on your DocumentRoot folder.

You can verify this by connecting to your instance through ssh and check the httpd config.

Comment: I attempted to change that already by ssh'ing into the ec2 instance and changing it, then restarting apache. my .htaccess files placed in every directory I could think of still didn't do anything. Any further guidance?